# Getting the error 2869 while adding custom actions to a C# setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools

I have created a C# setup project to deploy a C# windows application. I want to add custom prompt screens to my installation. So I have added a new "Installer" Class to my windows application and then overidden the "Install" method in it.

On right clicking SetUp project, in the "Custom Actions" window I added "primary output of the windows application", (where I have overridden "Install" method).

Later I set the "CustomActionData" property like this:

```
/txtBox1=[EDITA1]
```

And the argument property to `EDITA1`, where `EDITA1` is the identifier value for the text box that I have added to my custom prompt screen.

Inside the overridden Install method I am accessing this textBox value like this:

```
 Context.Parameter["txtBox"]
```

But when I try to install this package I am getting a pop up screen throwing error code 2869

The error popup messgae reads:

> The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2869.

Kindly let me know how shall I pass values from custom screen to the overridden install method.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Please take a moment to learn how to properly format your question so others don't have to do it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Ok I would take care of this from next time. Pardon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be

> /name="value" /name2="value". To pass installer properties the format is 
>   /name="[SourceDir]"

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has more details

Comment: I had a doubt if name in "/name= value" should be declared elsewhere prior to using here.    And in my context, I am not hardcoding the string into the /name=value of Custom Actions, instead, I am fetching values from a TEXTBOX, whose identifier is EDITA1.  So I have surrounded this by []. But I am getting error code 2869 while installing.

Comment: No "name" need not be declared anywhere. I tested it with /TestInfo="[EDITA1]". And could read the value set in the textbox. Are you running Vista? try to run the setup as Administrator (not directly from VS).

Comment: THANKS A LOT for such a speedy help, within minutes!! Hatts Off.  It worked. I am using Windows 7. I had to run with admin privileges.  Can you kindly let me one more thing, that is there any way to set the default installation location (Ofcourse we can click on BROWSE and change it but can one change the default installation location itself in any way).  THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Change the DefaultLocation property of Application Folder in FileSystem View. Right-click on Setup -> View - FileSystem -> Application Folder.

Comment: This too worked. THANK YOU very much for your kind speedy help.